# Print fragment of multiplication table

Tags: python, beginner, formatting

I am learning Python online on Stepik platform, and unfortunately I don't have any opportunity to get reviews from the tutor. The platform only checks the correctness of the answer that my program gives. So I decided to share the code here. Comments and corrections would be much appreciated.

> Write a program that print multiplication table
>   fragment for all numbers in the interval [a; b] for all of the
>   interval [c; d]

```
def print_mult_table(a, b, c, d):
    """
    Print multiplication table fragment for all numbers in the interval
    [:param a; :param b] for all of the interval [:param c; :param d]
    """
    m = list(list([i] + list(range(c * i, (d + 1) * i, i))) for i in ([1] + list(range(a, b + 1))))
    m[0][0] = ""    # This is done, because it is the desired output format
    max_width = len(str(m[-1][-1])) + 1
    for i in m:
        i = [str(j).rjust(max_width) for j in i]
        print('\t'.join(i))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make also this function a generator and make printing the responsibility of the caller. This makes the function more reusable.

```
def print_mult_table(row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end):
    """
    Print multiplication table fragment for all numbers in the interval
    [:param row_start; :param row_end] for all of the interval [:param col_start; :param col_end]
    """
    table = list(list([row] + list(range(col_start * row, (col_end + 1) * row, row))) for row in ([1] + list(range(row_start, row_end + 1))))
    table[0][0] = ""    # This is done, because it is the desired output format
    max_width = len(str(table[-1][-1])) + 1
    for row in table:
        yield '\t'.join(str(col).rjust(max_width) for col in row)

for row in print_mult_table(1, 10, 4, 8):
    print(row)
```

Note that I gave the variables easier to understand names. This makes the list comprehension longer. Which leads to the next point:

While the list comprehensions are nice and compact (with short incomprehensible variable names), they are starting to stretch what is still easily readable. A general rule is, if your list comprehension is longer than a line (80 characters) it is probably too complicated.  Therefore I would unfold it:

```
from itertools import chain


def get_mult_table(row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end):
    """
    Yield multiplication table fragment for all numbers in the interval
    [:param row_start; :param row_end] for all of the interval
    [:param col_start; :param col_end]
    """
    for row in chain([1], range(row_start, row_end + 1)):
        yield [col * row for col in chain([1], range(col_start, col_end + 1))]


def print_mult_table(row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end):
    table = list(get_mult_table(row_start, row_end, col_start, col_end))
    table[0][0] = ""    # This is done, because it is the desired output format
    max_width = len(str(table[-1][-1])) + 1
    for row in table:
        print '\t'.join(str(col).rjust(max_width) for col in row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_mult_table(1, 10, 4, 8)
```

This makes it a lot more obvious what happens (because it includes the actual multiplication, it is not hidden in the step size of the inner `range`). This might make it slightly slower (when generating multiplication tables from, say, 1 to 1,000,000).

It also separates the generation of the table from the actual printing logic.